# be more (of) sth than sth

Tags: prepositions, correlating-conjunctions

I am wondering what difference the preposition *of* makes in the following sentences:

It was more **of** a holiday than a training exercise.

It was more a worry than a pleasure.

Is *of* optional?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: In your context, ***of*** is indeed optional. My impression is that including it is likely to be seen as more formal/"proper" in AmE, whereas from the BrE perspective it's more of a "dialectal" usage.

Comment: **more of a** doesn't strike my AmE as more of a formality but as more of an informality.

Comment: I disagree with other comments. I wouldn't say that "of" is optional; it can be included or not, but they have very slightly different connotations to me.

Comment: @TomChurch Maybe you could reveal what those connotations are.

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comment against the question, I should say that it's only my *opinion* that some AmE speakers perceive including (syntactically optional) ***of*** to be somehow more "formal".

But I'd certainly consider the charts below good supporting evidence for my (BrE) perspective that if anything it has precisely *opposite* connotations. Both [the AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20was%20more%20a%2Cit%20was%20more%20of%20a%2Cit%27s%20more%20a%2Cit%27s%20more%20of%20a&year_start=1950&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20more%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20more%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20more%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20more%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0) results...

[image]

...and [the BrE results...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20was%20more%20a%2Cit%20was%20more%20of%20a%2Cit%27s%20more%20a%2Cit%27s%20more%20of%20a&year_start=1950&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20more%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20was%20more%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20more%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20more%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...show that ***of*** has gained significant traction in recent decades.

The reason I've contrasted ***it was*** and ***it's*** in those charts is because we can reasonably assume more of the former are in "formal" contexts, and more of the latter are "relaxed conversational" usages. Clearly only the colloquial contracted form actually *favours* including ***of*** in BrE (because at least some of us think it's ***a bit of a*** "hypercorrection" to use it in OP's *exact* context! :)

So noting that the ***of*** version has also overtaken the original simpler version in AmE, this *might* be because they don't share that "dialectal / uneducated" perspective that some Brits do.

---

Ordinarily, hardly anyone would notice much one way or the other in OP's exact context - but as implied by my whimsical comment above, it would be *more than a bit **of** a mistake* to omit the highlighted word in this very sentence.

But it's only *idiomatically* that it would be a "mistake" to discard ***of*** above. There are actually [these 2 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20bit%20more%20a%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI7eL_yrfZAhVHa8AKHa3LBs8QpwUIIQ&biw=1343&bih=755&dpr=1) of *a bit more a [noun]* without ***of*** in Google Books. They're both from the 1850s, before ***bit*** was commonly used in such contexts anyway. And I think it's impossible to make a *syntactic* case for saying that including ***more*** and/or whether the context is *more X **than Y*** should affect the grammaticality of the usage.

For example, idiomatically, I might say this is ***something of a self-referential sentence***, in that it uses an instance of the very construction OP is asking about. No-one would *ever* think of discarding ***of*** there, even though many wouldn't care much one way or the other if I'd replaced ***something*** with ***more***.

---

For the learner who just wants a reasonable "rule of thumb" here, I'd say the easiest thing is to always include ***of*** if all the following examples seem syntactically similar to you...

> *He was [more **of** a hindrance than](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more%20of%20a%20hindrance%20than%22) a help.* (24,600 hits in Google Books)
>    *That was [a bit **of** a mistake.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20bit%20of%20a%20mistake%22)* (43,100 hits)
>    *This [is something **of** a](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is%20something%20of%20a%22) self-referential sentence.* (1,540,000 hits)

Just ignore the possibility that some Brits might think you're a bit "rustic". In the long run we'll all be using ***of*** like this a lot more.

Comment: "I call B.S."  :)   https://books.google.com/books?id=j3341cQckbMC&pg=PT52&dq=%22it+was+more+of+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNtdy63rnZAhWoq1kKHX-tATsQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22it%20was%20more%20of%20a%22&f=false

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: You've lost me there. What's the connection?